# Do I need to check Parallel.ForEach for small workloads?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, parallel.foreach

I have a set of items in workload that can run in parallel. Sometimes there is just 1, sometimes there are *a lot*. It is noticeably faster when I Parallel.ForEach over a large workload. So it seems to be a suitable use of Parelle.ForEach.

I've read that for workloads of 1 or 2, it's better to not Parallel.ForEach over them. Does this mean I have to wrap every Parallel.ForEach of a variable workload size with this sort of pattern?

```
if (workItems.Count==1)
{
    foreach (MyItem item in workItems)
    {
        bool failed = WorkItWorkIt(item);
    }
}
else
{
    Parallel.ForEach(workItems, (item, loopState) =>
        {
            bool failed = WorkItWorkIt(item);
        });
}
```

Comment: You can find out the same way: measure. But it probably won't make much difference. The actual selection depends on the number of taska nd the size of a task.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, `Parallel.ForEach` with a single task will add a bit of overhead, but not tremendous.  `Parallel.ForEach` will actually reuse the main thread, which means there's really only some small checks, then it runs your work.  Two work items will be potentially worthwhile, and more is only better.

The bigger issue with `Parallel.ForEach` isn't actually the number of items in the collection, it's the amount and type of work being done *per item*.  If you have very small bodies (in terms of CPU time, etc), the cost of parallelizing can outweigh the benefits quickly.

If your work per item is CPU bound and reasonably large, then it's fairly safe to always parallelize, without checks.

That being said, the best solution, as always, is to actually profile your application with all of your various options.

Answer (score 2):

For most common tasks, the CPU cost of sometimes incurring the overhead of Parallel.ForEach() for small workloads will be small compared to the development cost of maintaining two code paths, one for small and one for large workloads.

Unless measurements in your use case indicate to the contrary, I would opt for a single Parallel.ForEach() implementation.

Answer (score -1):

It's definitely worth it if your task is critical - performance-wise - and specially if your method WorkItWorkIt() needs some kind of locking (e.g. write operations on a DataTable), but I wouldn't test it for 1 or 2 elements only. Instead, I'd have a threshold and decide based on the data set size what's the best strategy.
Example: I worked on a real test case where the Parallel.ForEach() would take 4 seconds to process 1200 rows in a DataTable, where the single-threaded linear *For* would do the same task in 2 seconds only (1/2 the time).